# Load package in Scheme48, how to get first, word variable, etc

Tags: scheme, scheme48

I just installed the scheme48 package from macports and have started experiencing. I was watching this youtube video, link [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAHA0nJv8EA) and was attempting to perform some of the examples. In the lecture the professor is running scheme on a Sun terminal. For example, I attempt to do '(first 473)' and get 'Error: undefined variable first'. Now, I'm assuming I haven't loaded the correct package / library or what ever it is called in scheme but am not sure what the syntax and library is. I believe that scheme48 and the scheme version on that sun terminal in the video are not the same and could be part of the problem.

So, what library do I need to use and how do I load it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lecture notes are based on a book called [Simply Scheme](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ss-toc2.html), and you can find the library code that is used in the book [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/downloads/simply/).  Specifically, you need [`simply.scm`](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/downloads/simply/simply.scm).

(But whether it is a good idea to have these kind of overloading functions is debatable.  Specifically, note that `first` is used in a way that is different from many other languages.)

Comment: hey thanks, just wanted to follow along in that video and play around with scheme and look a language that is not c based.